# Visual Studio 2022 auto prefix properties with "this"

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I would like that when I write the name of a property and I tab to autocomplete, it put "this" prefix automatically.

For exemple:
[image]

If I tab, I get this:
[image]

I would like to have this instead: [image]

There are my visual studio settings, Resharper settings and editorConfig:
[image]

[image]

[image]

(Edit: I've opened a feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-auto-prefix-propertie/10221630)

(Edit 2: The language is C#)

Comment: For what language? For Typescript, it already does that by default.

Answer (score 0):

This would need to be a feature request. You can submit that through VS with the Suggest A Feature on the feedback menu.

When you press tab to commit the completion item, the text to insert (or "insertion text") for that item has already been calculated.  In most cases, it is the text seen (known as the display text), but sometimes the insertion text can be different (or even include edits other places in the document!).  There is also the possibility, depending on how each language implements the completion feature, that the language can make additional calculations and edits as part of committing the item.

In either event (pre-computed or computed during commit), the language feature would need to make changes to include the `this.` prefix as part of the completion commit edit.

A possible alternative to waiting for a new feature would be to write an editor extension that monitors the buffer changes, and when it sees an applicable member inserted without the required `this.` prefix, it could then trigger its own edit automatically to insert it.